# Java Security encryption and decryption Validation rest service

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I am creating rest services for mobile client as consumer.

My requirement is to encrypt an random Integer and send to the client. The client will not do anything with that and sends that back again.

In the second request i need to get that encrypted value and decrypt it. After decryption I need to validate whether the value has changed or not.

How can I implement this using Java encryption decryption algorithms.

Since there is no session to store the old value, how do I compare the decrypted value with the original to make sure both are same.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [The Comprehensive Guide to URL Parameter Encryption in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)

Comment: Maybe you did not give all the details, but how is this useful? Instead of encrypting and decrypting a random integer you could just send the random integer itself forth and back.

Comment: @Henry yes i did some abstraction as my logic was more generalized to my company need. let me put in other words.

Comment: there will be a id associated with each customer. Request 1: client will ask for validation of the customer based on  some inputs. Server will validate based on that inputs and retrieve an id that is already stored in the database. Response to Req 1: more info like email address will be sent to client back. Now client will ask for the user to register a new account and send the credentials back to server which is request 2.

Comment: Server has to update the database those credentials and link that credentials to the id retrieved while processing request 1. since the id value has to be carried forward to more than one request response, that id has be sent in encrypted form in response 1 and decrypted again in request 2. while decrypting in request 2 check has to be made sure that encrypted value is not changed in between [some attack may be]. and the credentials are linked to right id.

Comment: i need a mechanism to validate this id in response 2 and not saving the credentials if the id is wrong. any encryption decryption logic in java does this ? any help ? thanks